# The performance of converting strings using marshal_as function

Tags: .net, c++, managed-c++

Currently I am trying to convert String^ to std::string using marshal_as function (Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx). Does anyone know the performance of this conversion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion: use it. If your code runs fast enough, then don't worry about it. It's highly unlikely that converting your strings is going to be a bottleneck. If profiling shows that it *is* a bottleneck, it's probable that your problem isn't with `marshal_as` (which I would expect to be very fast), but rather that your code is making too many conversions between types.